# PHP login form doesn't work

Tags: php

I don't know why I am wrong but this login form doesn't work for me. My login form gives me the error "Incorrect login details"! I am not sure if there is a problem accesing data from database.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('dbconnect.php');


if (isset($_POST['login'])){
//  verifica daca exista date transmise
if ($_POST['log_username'] != "" && $_POST['log_pass'] != '') {


    $username = $_POST['log_username'];
    $password = $_POST['log_pass'];


    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'") or die ( "Error : ". mysql_error());


    if ($result || mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) {
        // daca nu, afiseaza un mesaj de eroare
        echo "Incorrect login details!";
    } else {


        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;


        echo "Autentificarea a fost efectuata cu succes.";
    }
}
}
?>
```

here is the html code part:

```
<form action='' method='post'>                      
    <ul class="form-style-1">
        <header id="header" class="info"><h1>Login</h1></header>
        <li>
        <label>Username</label><input type="text" name="log_username" class="field-long" />
        </li>                       
        <li>
        <label>Parola</span></label><input type="password" name="log_pass" class="field-long" />
        </li>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type='submit' value='Login' name='login'/>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: `if (!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) {`

Comment: Consider using password_hash() and password_verify() instead of storing plain text passwords

Comment: This code has a SQL injection vulnerability - it may get hacked if you put it live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try separate the variables on if statement:

```
if (($result < 1) || (mysql_num_rows($result) < 1)) 
{
...
}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in the PHP-code. When you get the `$result`, you run it throught an if-statement;

```
if ($result || mysql_num_rows($result) < 1)
```

shouldn't it be

```
if (!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) < 1)
```

If you do not get a result `(!$result)` --> `echo out ""Incorrect login details!"`.

Comment: Thank you @Gab. I am new here ;) Forgot the code-tags.

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) {
    // daca nu, afiseaza un mesaj
}else{
}
```

NB: there is serious security issues in your code. Saving your password in session and no data validation and SQL injection.